# d3 custom date format

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have received a request from a client for a  project burndown chart using a line graph. The problem is they want the date on the x-axis to be formatted in a particular way mmm dd-dd/yy (e.g. Nov 18-24/12) where 18-24 is a week (18th through the 24th). Is it possible to create a custom date format in D3, If not what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went with creating my own format specifier "%o"

```
o: function(d) {
    var weekInSeconds = 6 * 86400000;
    var eowDate = new Date(d.getTime() + weekInSeconds);
    return d3_time_zfill2(eowDate.getDate());
},
```

around line 6824 in the d3.v2.js file. Not the cleanest implementation but it works.

Comment: There are ways to create your own date format functions without editing the d3.js code itself (I showed two ways in my answer).  Doing it this way is definitely not recommended.  If you ever update d3 in the future, you'll lose this functionality which will probably break your app unexpectedly.

Comment: Since you only seem to have a single tick format, I would just use code similar to the one I posted in my response.  Just return the desired string based on the date passed into `customDateFormat`.

Comment: `%L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].` per https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create a custom date format.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(customDateFormat);

function customDateFormat(date) {
  // figure out what week the current date is in
  // and return the appropriate string
}
```

If you want to be even fancier, you can implement a full formatter in the same way that d3.js implemented the built in formatter.  See http://bl.ocks.org/4149176 for an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. See [the documentation on `d3.time.format`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

Comment: I was looking on that earlier and I do not see a specifier that will help me achieve the starting and end date requirement (18-24) of the date format.

Comment: You would need to do this in two parts -- a format that does the start part (month day) and takes the start of the week date and a format that takes the end of the week and produces (day/year). To the best of my knowledge, there is nothing that will give you what you want out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've used javascript to sort/format the date and then send the value to D3 in the past when it comes to unconventional formats.

I've used [date.js](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html). It's an older js library but it gets the job done and it offers a wide range of formats.